# PhoneGap/Cordova with Intellij Idea console.log

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, cordova

I am starting new project and use Cordova there. I write console.log ('text') but not see it in Logcat of Intellij. I used some tutorials to filter output (with title Web Console) of logcat, but see only log entries from Web Console with JS errors. So what can be wrong?

Comment: please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373491/android-logcat-is-not-working-for-js-console-log - does it help?