# Debugging a WebView (Ionic) app on Android via logcat

Tags: android, cordova, adb, ionic-framework, logcat

There are several questions about the subject, however not one of them seems to address the particular problem I'm having.

I'm developing an app with Cordova/Ionic, and printing debugging info I was outputting with `console.log()` by using `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S` was working just fine until some updates. Now I can't seem to figure out how to properly filter logcat's output so I could only get the debugging info from my app.

Logging itself works. If I set no filters and redirect output to a file, I can see my debugging info among all the other debug messages, and it looks like this:

```
I/Web Console: Event triggered: device.ready:1
```

Logging to screen also works, but at a rate of approximately 100 lines per second. I've tried at least the following to filter output:

```
adb logcat -s "Web Console"
adb logcat "Web Console":V
adb logcat "Web Console":*
adb logcat -s Web
adb logcat Web:V
adb logcat "myApp":V
adb logcat myApp:V
adb logcat -s myApp
```

... and probably others I've already forgotten. They either print absolutely nothing, or absolutely everything from the system services.

I'm on Windows so I can't `grep`, and the device I'm debugging on is running Android 4.2.2 so I can't use GapDebug, and neither does it seem to be possible to access the device's log via `chrome://inspect` in Chrome.

I really, really would like to understand how filtering logcat's output works. I'm not willing to log everything to a file and then shift through that.

Comment: `adb logcat -s "Web Console":*`... I'd recommend not to use spaces in the tag name though

Comment: @AlexP. nope, still nada. The tag is defined by Cordova, and I have no idea how to change that. It used to be CordovaLog and like I said then everything worked beautifully. Either the info on how to change the tag name doesn't exist in the docs, or my Google Fu fails me miserably.

Comment: `adb shell "logcat -s 'Web Console':*"`

Comment: @AlexP. Thanks, but still the same result. :( Absolutely no output. Perhaps the tag really can't have a space in it.

Comment: well there's always `adb shell "logcat | grep 'Web Console'"`

Comment: @AlexP. Yes! That's the one! Please make an answer out of it so I can accept it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems that `logcat` can not properly parse tag names with whitespaces. So instead I suggest using `grep` on the device:

```
adb shell "logcat | grep 'Web Console'"
```

Comment: saved a lot of head ache

Comment: I just type `adb logcat | grep app=mi`

Comment: In my case filtering by "Web Console" didn't work, but worked by "chromium": `adb shell "logcat | grep 'chromium'"`

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively when runing adb on linux or unix based os/git bash:

```
adb logcat | grep 'Web Console'
```

Answer (score 5):

What works for me in 2019:

```
adb -d logcat chromium:I *:S
```

The `-d` indicating a physical device in my case. If all else fails just dump the results of `adb logcat` into a text file and do a search for "CONSOLE", that will give you the provider for your logcat filter. It seems this changes over time, and depending on your particular dev environment.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me! Thank you

Comment: and also in 2020

Answer (score 2):

While you can use `grep` under Linux/Unix, `findstr` might be your choice under Windows:

```
adb logcat | findstr /C:"Web Console"
```

If you prefer to use `grep` under Windows, you can get it from 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm.

Comment: the accepted answer works the same in all 3 supported operating systems. no need for windows only solution

Comment: You are absolutely right (grep works on all major OS) - I postet this answer a) to target users that are not too familiar with the GNU tools b) to take into account that the user stated "I'm on Windows so I can't grep" and c) to provide a link to grep (once more to target users that mostly work under windows and might not even know of grep)

Comment: you are missing the point that in the accepted answer `grep` runs on the device itself. so it does not matter if `grep` is available on the host PC system

Comment: I did indeed - very good point - your answer could also improve the performance of the logging if you run the application on a physical device as the host running adb will not have to filter the whole log (leaving it to the device to do the filtering)