# Android, adb: How I can do command: "adb logcat|grep com.myproject" on Windows machine?

Tags: android, windows, adb

1. I need to redirect output of "**adb logcat**"
2. Also I need to filter this output. To show only text that contain text: *com.myproject*

So in Linux machine I use the next command in console:

```
adb logcat|grep com.myproject
```

And it's work fine. OK.

Now I need to do same on Windows 10 machine. Windows machine has no **grep** 
utility.

So, how I can do this in Windows?

P.S. Windows 10 machine is not my. I has no credentials to install anything.

Comment: you can just run `grep` on the device instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248867/1778421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install and use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), it gives you many Unix tools like `grep`

Comment: This is not my  machine. I has no credentials to install anything.

Comment: @lmdic Ok, you should search for grep alternative, maybe you find anything like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846697/3678849

Comment: @RuNo280 Unfortunately findstr won't work with adb logcat.