# How can I get webview console log through adb?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview

I am building an Android application with `Cordova` which is running inside a webview. I know I can access the webview via `chrome://inspect` but it only works for debug build. It can't inspect the chrome in release APK. So is there a way to get the chrome console log via `adb` command?

Comment: Are you using a particular framework or tool to build your app or are you just putting HTML5/Javascript into a simple native (Java/Kotlin) Android app wrapping a WebView?

Comment: I am using `Cordova` and I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: This question/answers may help [Debugging WebView in  apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711418/debugging-webview-in-react-native-apps/48572075#48572075)

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't find this *anywhere* on SO, here's what worked for me:

```
adb -d logcat chromium:I *:S
```

The `-d` indicating a physical device in my case. If all else fails just dump the results of `adb logcat` into a text file and do a search for "CONSOLE", that will give you the provider for your logcat filter. It seems this changes over time, and depending on your particular dev environment.

Answer (score 2):

For getting the console log via adb see: [Debugging a WebView (Ionic) app on Android via logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30247308/295004)

Try the above first as I seem to misread your question about debugging a WebView via remote debugging, which is what follows.

For a simple native Java/Kotlin Android app wrapping a WebView, [the documentation is quite clear that all one needs to do is to enable the feature](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews#configure_webviews_for_debugging):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

and additional code is required to limit it to debug version:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
    { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
}
```

Looking at what is in the Cordova Android repo:

[Cordova Android - ... SystemWebViewEngine.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/46a036ef265951d5371936b37d7296fa47fb28ce/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewEngine.java)

the relevant code is here:

```
//Determine whether we're in debug or release mode, and turn on Debugging!
ApplicationInfo appInfo = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
    enableRemoteDebugging();
}
```

I also found this open [ISSUE 500: Release version still have debugging enabled](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/500) which implies that Android Emulators are allow for debugging even though the APK is packaged for release.

So my suggestions for remote debugging a WebView on a release APK are:

1. Try to use the emulator for debugging with a release APK as it appears to be possible.
2. Consider forking the Cordova Android code and create a special debug mode so that on device it would be possible to debug the contents of a WebView. Enabling such a feature could be hidden via a custom system property: [How to define and use a system property in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3750109/295004) For example say you defined the flag to be named `com.example.myapp.debugwebview`. You could set the property via command like `adb setprop com.example.myapp.debugwebview 1` and on start/restart the app would enable WebView debugging. Note that this does require a more detailed understanding of Android to support such a feature, as well as the effort of supporting a fork.