# How do I get rid of an uncalled padStart Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an HTML5 Cordova App. I am using JQuery and Pure JS to fetch data from the server and implement other dynamic functions. My problem is that at some point in my app, I am fetching some data via ajax and use jquery to dynamically create a table and populate it with the fetched data and then navigate or change the view to where I am appending the table.

When I run this in my browser it work just fine, but when I build the app and run it on my mobile device, it throws `TypeError: String(...).padStart is not a function`. I know this because I am alerting the error in my `catch` clause. What's strange is that I have not use the `padStart()` function anywhere in my code.

See the below code

```
createTableDOM(response,function(res){
     if(res=="Done"){
        changeView('data_preview_view');
     }
})
function createTableDOM(json, back) {
    var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    let table = $("<table/>");
    let tbody = $("<tbody>/");

    //CREATE ELEMENTS
    let div = $("<div/>");
    div.addClass("col s12");
    div.css({ "padding": ".2em;", "background": "black", "color": "white" });

    let h1 = $("<h1/>");
    h1.css("width", "100%");
    h1.html("TICKET # :" + json.ticket_number);

    div.append(h1);

    let row1 = $("<tr>/");
    let td1a = $("<td>/");
    td1a.html("Market Code: ");
    let td1b = $("<td>/");
    td1b.css("text-align", "right");
    td1b.html(json.data.market);
    row1.append(td1a, td1b);

    let row2 = $("<tr>/");
    let td2a = $("<td>/");
    td2a.html("Name: ");
    let td2b = $("<td>/");
    td2b.css("text-align", "right");
    td2b.html(json.data.business_name);
    row2.append(td2a, td2b);

    let row3 = $("<tr>/");
    let td3a = $("<td>/");
    td3a.html("Contact: ");
    let td3b = $("<td>/");
    td3b.css("text-align", "right");
    td3b.html(json.data.phone_number);
    row3.append(td3a, td3b);

    let row4 = $("<tr>/");
    let td4a = $("<td>/");
    td4a.html("Time: ");
    let td4b = $("<td>/");
    td4b.css("text-align", "right");
    td4b.html(time);
    row4.append(td4a, td4b);

    let row5 = $("<tr>/");
    let td5a = $("<td>/");
    td5a.html("Date: ");
    let td5b = $("<td>/");
    td5b.css("text-align", "right");
    td5b.html(getCurrentDate());
    row5.append(td5a, td5b);

    let row6 = $("<tr>/");
    let td6a = $("<td>/");
    td6a.html("Revenue Type: ");
    let td6b = $("<td>/");
    td6b.css("text-align", "right");
    td6b.html("Market Fee");
    row6.append(td6a, td6b);

    let row7 = $("<tr>/");
    let td7a = $("<td>/");
    td7a.html("Fee: ");
    let td7b = $("<td>/");
    td7b.css("text-align", "right");
    td7b.html("K100");
    row7.append(td7a, td7b);


    tbody.append(row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7);
    table.append(tbody);

    var parent = $("#table_div");
    parent.empty();
    parent.append(div,table);

    back("Done");
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete error stack trace?

Comment: I am only getting this error when I build and run this app on my phone. So I am not really sure how to grab the entire stack trace, but I can do a screen shot

Comment: @CliffTheCoder the point is, if you're getting that error and that method is not explicitly called in your code, it means that something in your code is calling something that is calling something... that calls that method. Seeing the stack trace would help in understanding what that initial something is.

Comment: Alright sure. i'll try to find a way to get full stack trace

Comment: Guys I am still struggling with this Exception. @FedericoklezCulloca,  you suggested that reading the entire stack trace might help understand what is initializing this in the first place. The challenge is that this is only occurring once I build the app and run it on on my Android device, I cant do a ```console.log(error)``` since I won't be able to see the output at all, the best that I am able to do is ```alert(error) ``` which only displays: ```String(...).padStart is not a function```. I am open to any suggestions on how I can view the entire stack trace.

Comment: You should be able to use `logcat` to see console log messages. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247308/debugging-a-webview-ionic-app-on-android-via-logcat) for some pointers.

Comment: I have downloaded Android Debugging Bridge and  tried out a couple of commands as per your link. I am having a difficult time navigating and getting a hang of it. I have also discovered that the problem does not occur on other devices, Just this one (HandHeld Andriod Thermal Printer).